# Android - Efficient way to compare elements of Array/Arraylist to precheck checkboxes

Tags: java, android, arrays, list, arraylist

In want to load the user quiz results in my Android quiz application. I'm getting the results from my database as String. In the next step I'm converting this String to an array and then to an arraylist. Then I'm iterating throug the list to get the ids of the checkboxes, comparing them and check them if they match.

```
        userResultCursor = db.getUserResults(question.getId());
        if (userResultCursor != null && userResultCursor.getCount() != 0) {
            String resultString = userResultCursor
                    .getString(userResultCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MyDatabase.ResultColumns.RESULT));
            String resultArray[] = convertStringToArray(resultString);
            List<String> resultList = Arrays.asList(resultArray);

            for (String id : resultList) {
                if (cb_answer1.getId() == Integer.parseInt(id)) {
                    cb_answer1.setChecked(true);
                }

                if (cb_answer2.getId() == Integer.parseInt(id)) {
                    cb_answer2.setChecked(true);
                }

                if (cb_answer3.getId() == Integer.parseInt(id)) {
                    cb_answer3.setChecked(true);
                }

                if (cb_answer4.getId() == Integer.parseInt(id)) {
                    cb_answer4.setChecked(true);
                }

                if (cb_answer5.getId() == Integer.parseInt(id)) {
                    cb_answer5.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
        }
```

I actually don't like this solution because it looks very awkward.
I think there is a much better solution for this.
Do you have any tips to get the same result in a efficient way?

Comment: No matter which way you do it, there is going to be iteration and checking, which is all you have here. If you want it to look better, get rid of the if blocks and use `cb_answerX.setChecked(cb_answerX.getId() == Integer.parseInt(id));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shorten this code, but in terms of performance, it can't really be more efficient as far as I'm concerned.

You see those repeating `cb_answer1`, `cb_answer2`, `cb_answer3`? That means you probably need an array:

```
CheckBox[] answerCheckBoxes = { cb_answer1, cb_answer2, cb_answer3 } 
// I'm lazy. Please add the rest in yourself
```

Now you can loop through it:

```
for (CheckBox cb : answerCheckBoxes) {
    if (cb.getId() == Integer.parseInt(id)) {
        cb.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But that means I have 2 for-loops now. Can it become more efficient if I do so?

Comment: @DenoAgüero Well, no. Because as far as I'm concerned,  the performance can't be improved by a noticeable amount. All you can do is shorten the code.

Comment: @DenoAgüero If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that check mark.

Comment: I would also add a `break;` statement after `cb.setChecked(true);` so the `for` loop doesn't loop through the rest of checkboxes when it finds right checkbox.